# QEMU/KVM: how to protect monitor access?

Tags: security, kvm-virtualization, network-security

Runing QEMU/KVM with monitor: `kvm ...some_parameters... -monitor unix:/my_path/my_fifo,server,nowait`

We can then connect using `socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/my_path/my_fifo` then type commands.
Easy and handy.

I'd like to expose the monitor interface to the local network (probably using socat, according to the securing method), which is resonably safe. How can I protect access to the monitor?

I do not see any available password option, certificate, etc. So I suspect I have to rely on a method external to QEMU/KVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSH to access such a socket securely, leveraging the security options provided by SSH. You don't need `socat` at all, because SSH allows forwarding socket-to-socket or tcp-to-socket via `-L` option:

```
     -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
     -L [bind_address:]port:remote_socket
     -L local_socket:host:hostport
     -L local_socket:remote_socket
```

E.g. if your `qemu` process runs with `-monitor unix:/my_path/my_fifo,server,nowait` option, use `ssh virtualization-host -L /tmp/monitor:/my_path/my_fifo` to connect, and then connect to local socket `/tmp/monitor`, or use `ssh virtualization-host -L 12345:/my_path/my_fifo` and telnet to `localhost:12345` (SSH client will listen only on localhost in this case).

To achieve better security, use SSH keys to connect to monitors. On the remote virtualization host, create a user who'll have `rw` rights on the `/my_path/my_fifo` object. Create a key pair and put the public key into that user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in a restricted way to only allow forwarding:

```
restrict,port-forwarding,command="/bin/false" ssh-... ..... (the public key string)
```

To connect, use a command which doesn't allocate a shell and doesn't run a command, useful just for forwards:

```
ssh monitoruser@virtualization-host -i mointor_private_key -L 12345:/my_path/my_fifo -N
```

and finally, use `telnet localhost 12345` to access the monitor socket forwarded via SSH.